# Fail to get my apache2 to connect externaly

Tags: networking, server, apache2, moodle

Hey im really i the need of help
im running hyper-v with 2 servers one with bigbluebutton - works like a charm also from outside.
and one with moodle installed on apache2- works like shit!

So i have it up running on lan and can connect but only on lan! 192.168.1.4
i need to get it through from outside from port 80.

I am not running them together atm. so only 1 server is portforwarding to 80 and that is the moodle one.

So i can reach everything fine from lan but not from outside ip what to do.
I have read for 3 days now about virtual host but i dont even know if i am needing one.  if so please advice me where and what/how i would really apriciate it ::)

Best regards Mike

Comment: Are you on a residential connection?

Comment: Probably an issue with your router/routing setup. You said BBB was working properly? Did you have to do any router setting modifications to get it to work properly?

Comment: okay i have change the port to 850 and now i get through but!!
its only showing me directory to moodle.
i $ a2dismod autoindex but now i get Not found...

Comment: And no Brian, all i did were forwarding. and that worked like a charm.

Comment: NOW i have copied the moodle content from var/www/html/moodle to var/www/html/  and it goes to lan ip 192.168.1.4 ??

Comment: **okay** so i now have fixed the problem by configuration the config.php from www/html/ and set `$CFG->wwwroot = 'http:domain.dns.com:port';`
So this brings up a new question can I get rid of the portnumber?
Im going to start KEMP reverse proxy to handel 2 different dyn dyn.doman.com - dyn2.domain.com ??